# Oracle JDBC TLS connection fails (handshake_failure) after OS upgrade

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, connectivity, ssl

I have an Oracle Database 12.1 server running on Oracle Linux 6.

Secure (TLS) connections were working fine until I decided to update the underlying operating system (`yum update`) and reboot the server. A total of 62 packages were updated ([yum update log](https://gist.github.com/dleborgne/a02e3567eab2c1f3b33180a4c5c67aff)) including the kernel and OpenSSL.

Now, secure connections, from the JDBC clients and from SQL*Plus fails with handshake_failure or ORA-28860.

I have a [verbose TLSv1.2 log](https://gist.github.com/dleborgne/b3b16e0075e4a381403c2465b6befa23) from my JDBC client but I can't figure out what is wrong with the TLS connection.

[listener.ora](https://gist.github.com/dleborgne/c53ee2f85ea5fba8d2513f6581b44f86) and [sqlnet.ora](https://gist.github.com/dleborgne/3db7ca23a7a51f261d98b4245622581c)

`sqlnet.ora` and `listener.ora` do not contain `SSL_CIPHER_SUITES`

I am sure that nothing was changed or updated on the client (either JDBC or SQL*Plus). Few minutes before the upgrade/reboot, there was no problem establishing the TLS connection.

The server runs Oracle 12.1.0.1. The TLS connection issue occurs with all tested clients which previously succeeded in establishing a secure connection:

- ojdbc8.jar 12.2.0.1
- ojdbc7.jar 12.1.0.2
- SQL*Plus 12.1.0.2.0.

The [SQL*Plus trace file](https://gist.github.com/dleborgne/8b54379a8286a58466a3756d3435981f) contains an ORA-28862 ("peer closed the connection") which may be more specific than the previous ORA-28860. I will try to get the same trace file on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the listener solved the issue... I can't understand what happened, as the listener was already restarted during the server reboot.

I should have tried that before.

Thanks to everyone who has taken time to help.